# Git - in config file, what changes if I init or clone?

Tags: git

I did the following.

First, I did a `git init` on a project folder. I added all the files and committed.

Then I initialized an empty repo on my Dropbox, using `git init --bare`.

Then I did a `git remote add dropbox DROPBOX_PATH` and pushed there.

Looking at my `.git/config`, I have the lines:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = false
[remote "dropbox"]
    url = /Users/whatyouhide/Dropbox/Repos/studiolegaleleopardi.it
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/dropbox/*
```

Then I went to my second computer and did a:

```
git clone --origin dropbox DROPBOX_PATH
```

Looking at `.git/config` on my second computer (the one in which I **cloned** the repo) I have two additional lines:

```
[branch "master"]
    remote = dropbox
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

I guess those lines are important, because then when I `git fetch` from the first computer I don't see the message

```
Your branch is ahead of 'dropbox/master' by 1 commit.
```

which I see on my second computer (the one who cloned).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[branch "master"]` section means that your `master` branch in set up to automatically track the `master` branch in the dropbox repository. This means that when you push and pull, it will automatically know which remote branch it is pushing and pulling from.

If you clone a new repository, it automatically sets up the `master` branch of the new clone to track the `master` in your dropbox. It is up to you to configure the dropbox `master` to track the `master` in your original repository.

You can do this by running this in your original repo:

```
git branch master --set-upstream dropbox/master
```

You could also have done it like this when you originally pushed to dropbox's master:

```
git push -u dropbox master
```

Now when you run `get status` it will know what remote repository to compare to.

Comment: So the `-u` option "fixes" this? I mean, I want to have the same identical repo on both of my computers. Basically, I love when I can `git status` and get back a `You are ahead of etc.`, so that I can see on my first computer if my second computer made some new changes.

Comment: Also, should I run `-u` everytime I push (and from both computers?) or just the first time?

Comment: `-u` sets up the local branch to track the remote one, so after it is set up you don't need to set it again. From then on you can just to `git push` and it will automatically know to push to `dropbox/master`.

Comment: ok, that worked like a charm. I get exactly what I wanted, that is the wonderful `You are ahead ... by X commits ...` message. Still, I really didn't get what is going on! I have to dig inside `git` I guess :)